# sublime.getClipboard: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getClipboard'

Tags: python

I try to create simple `sublime 3` plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os.path

class RelativeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, sublime.getClipboard())
```

It must insert current file path to beginning of current file.

I found method `sublime.getClipboard()` [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api-reference).

But it fails:

```
File "/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/relative/relative.py", line 7, in run
    self.view.insert(edit, 0, sublime.getClipboard())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getClipboard'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know why, but method name is actually `get_clipboard`

```
sublime.get_clipboard()
```

Allthough in [documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api-reference) it is `getClipboard`